# No se genera el archivo config/puma.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quiero pasar un proyecto de Ruby on Rails a producción que tengo tiempo desarrollando usando puma y nginx.

Siguiendo los consejos de este enlace:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Pero en la parte de configuración del servidor de puma, me dice que debo agregar cierta configuración al archivo **config/puma.rb** y no lo veo en esa carpeta ni en ningún lado.

Hasta ahora he probado desinstalar la gema de puma e instalar y nada.

Probé crear un proyecto nuevo `$ rails new proyecto` y si se genera el archivo **config/puma.rb**, probé copiar ese archivo en la carpeta config de mi proyecto y no lo lee.

¿alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: ¿pero has probado simplemente creando el archivo y pegando lo que sale en [el link que mandas](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#configure-puma)?

Comment: Si, cree el archivo, ya funciona, el problema era una variable que estaba cambiada, tuve que releer el archivo config/puma.rb palabra por palabra.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Rails tiene tu proyecto?

Comment: Fijate si te sirve lo que recomiendan en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911994/2191500

Comment: $ rails -v
Rails 5.2.3